# How to show that $A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am trying this problem. Could not proceed . Please give a hint.

The exercise, if the above image is not showing clearly, is the following: Let $A$ and $B$ be two square $m \times m$ matrices for some integer $m \ge 2$ such that $A+B$ is invertible. Then show that
the equation $A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A$. [Note that either $A$ or $B$ or each of both may not be invertible, and that $A$ and $B$ may not commute.]

Comment: Please at least take the time to write out the question instead of using a blurry image. The title is also unhelpfully vague.

Answer (score 2):

First note the following equation:

$$A(A+B)^{-1}(A+B) = (A+B)(A+B)^{-1}A.$$

[Indeed, both sides of this equation just above are $A$.] That hint may or may not be enough. If you want more help, see below:

> Distributing on each side gives.....

> $$A(A+B)^{-1}A +A(A+B)^{-1}B = A(A+B)^{-1}A + B(A+B)^{-1}A.$$

> But then subtracting both sides by $A(A+B)^{-1}A$ gives

> $$A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A,$$

> which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write
$$
A(A + B)^{-1}B = 
[(A + B) - B](A + B)^{-1}B
$$
and distribute.

---

Alternatively, we can reduce our consideration to the case that $A$ is invertible and then deduce the general result using the continuity of matrix operations. In particular, if $A$ is invertible we can write
$$
A(A + B)^{-1}B = A([I + BA^{-1}]A)^{-1}B \\
= A(A^{-1} [I + (BA^{-1})]^{-1})B \\
= [I + (BA^{-1})]B\\
= [I + (BA^{-1})](BA^{-1})A\\
= (BA^{-1})[I + (BA^{-1})]A.
$$

Comment: But here $A$ is not given to be invertible..

Comment: @chayanikasarma So you are checking your messages! Please write out the question in the image, as was requested in Theophile's comment on your post

Comment: @chayanikasarma Instructions on how to format mathematical expressions are given [on this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @chayanikasarma And yes: $A$ is not necessarily invertible, hence the need to "deduce the general result using the continuity of matrix operations".

Answer (score -1):

You can try prove:

$$
A(A+B)^{-1} B * (B(A+B)^{-1}A)^{-1}=I
$$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ may not be invertible, so this does not work.  Also  inverting a product of matrices reverses the order.